# How to create a Bulletin Board for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a bulletin board for my wordpress website.It a place where we can write updates on, event planing promotional stuffs etc. I tried many plugins like WP Bulletin Board, bbpress etc. But they are too complex. Is there any simple plugin by which i can create a bulletin board?

Comment: how on earth did this get one upvote?

Comment: @user3791372 Why not? because i have searched a lot and couldn't find a solution. That's why i posted it here...

Comment: @starjijo read this: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you create a new custom post type and use it as bulletin board?

```
function bb_custom_post_event() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Events', 'post type general name' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Event', 'post type singular name' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'event' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Event' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Event' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Event' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'All Events' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Events' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Events' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No events found' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No events found in the Trash' ), 
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
    'menu_name'          => 'Bulletin Board'
  );
  $args = array(
    'labels'        => $labels,
    'description'   => '',
    'public'        => true,
    'menu_position' => 25,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-calendar',
    'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
    'has_archive'   => true,
  );
  register_post_type( 'event', $args ); 
}
add_action( 'init', 'bb_custom_post_event' );
```

Paste the Above code in your functions.php file and you will have a brand new event section that behaves exactly like the posts.

If you give me a little bit more info I might be able to customise the code a little bit more for you

Comment: I added the code. Whats next?

Comment: Can you see the new menu Item called Bulletin Board with a calendar icon? should be after Comments

Comment: yup.. i can see that. But after publishing, when i view it, it shows Error 404 - Page Not Found.

Comment: Flush the permalinks: settings->permalinks and click on Save Changes.

Comment: Now you should tell me how would you like to display the entries so that I can help you